# Ошибка при работе с базой данных в java, androidStudio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Пожалуйста скажите почему у меня здесь подчёркивается красным
[image]

И помогите пожалуйста решить проблему

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У Вас вместо db  должно быть sqLiteDatabase(переменная передается методом)

Comment: просто в этом видео https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=guHJbPYKHUU на 10:35 там используется так как в моём скриншоте?

Comment: В этом видео методу onCreate передают параметр с именем db, а у Вас - sqLiteDatabase(см. на параметры методом внимательнее)

Comment: так это всё правильно и db и sqLiteDatabase?

Comment: Нет, просто замените db.execSQL(query); ===> sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(query);

Comment: спасибо большое, вы мне очень помогли : )